# What is the meaning of "there's just no talking to you sometimes"?

Tags: meaning

In Crime/Drama movie *Drugstore Cowboy*, Rick and Nadine have some conversation.
Nadine put the hat on the bed.

> Nadine: You're just goin' out with them tonight. When you come back,
>   I'll show all of you.
>
> Rick: When I come back, I don't want to see that hat on the bed. All
>   right, honey? You know, Nadine, **there's just no talking to you
>   sometimes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/there-s-no-doing-something), "there's no doing something" is an idiom which is used to emphasize in informal English that it's not possible or permitted to do something.

"There's just no talking to you sometimes" means that it's just not possible to talk to you sometimes.